# How do I use browserify with multiple document.ready()?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I have seen lots of browserify examples with one page, but none with multiples pages (with document.ready()). An example below.

> page1.html

```
<script src="js/page1.js"></script>
```

> page1.js

```
var $ = require("jquery");
$(function(){
  console.log("page1.js");
  //do stuff witch jquery
});
```

> page2.html

```
<script src="js/page2.js"></script>
```

> page2.js

```
var $ = require("jquery");
var _ = require("underscore");
$(function(){
  console.log("page2.js");
  //do stuff witch jquery and underscore
});
```

Please notice that I need to execute code on page load for every page.
I know I can do `browserify page1.js -o bundle1.js` and `browserify page2.js -o bundle2.js` and include bundleX.js instead of the pageX.js in my page.
So do I have to do this for every single page ? I have like 10 pages, this doesn't seem right.

From the examples I have seen on browserify, there is always on entry point (often called main.js or app.js). I think I should have only one entry point, but I don't know how to refactor the code above.

Comment: As far as I remember, there is no problem having multiple `$(document).ready()` with jQuery. Have you tested it?

Comment: I didn't say there was issues having multiple $(document).ready(), but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer, just to understand what is your problem. I think I've understood it now. You want to have customized javascript bundles for each page in your application, am I right?

Comment: I wish I have only one bundle for the whole website, all the examples seem to show it should be this way, but I don't know how to handle the multiple $(document).ready() case above.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a hard question to answer because it really depends on how you're trying to architect your code. I'm guessing that's why someone downvoted you.)

Since you have different things you want to do on document ready, it seems natural that you'd do something like you show here - have different scripts for each entry point (each page).

Rather than manually invoking Browserify for each of the bundles you're developing, you should use a tool like Grunt or Gulp. With either of these you can configure a command-line task that watches your source files and automatically runs Browserify for you whenever something changes. I haven't set this up for Gulp, but for Grunt I can point you to the [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) plugin.

Comment: I know about Grunt and Gulp with watchify/browserify plugins. I'am just wondering how is browserify supposed to work in my case (which isn't even far-fetched, it's common to have js in a doc.ready()).